# Update sub class in EF MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, edit

Have models:

```
public class Company
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? AddressId { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; } 
}
```

The simplified Edit view is:

```
@model ChickCRM.Models.Company

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{    
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AddressId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Address.ID)    

    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
    <br />
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address.Street)

    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

1) I dont know how to update Address properties in Company Edit method (it just updates company properites, not Street).
I mean something like:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Company company)
    {
            db.Entry(company).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("");
    }
```

2) I dont know how to use validation Include attribute for sub-property Address.Street (if I want to use it)

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,Name,AddressId,Address.Street")] Company company)
...
```

Comment: You need to show your view. And by default, all properties are 'included' so if you want to post all values, remove the `[Bind]` attribute.

Comment: I added the view in my request..

Comment: That looks OK, but are you wanting to save a new street name for the existing address? (in which case you would also need to save the address - currently you are only saving the company)

Comment: Ok Stephen. I am just starting with EF and dont understand it well. I tried to add somethink like this but I had an error (about foreign keys). But now it goes well. So thank you.

db.Entry(company.Address).State = EntityState.Modified;

Comment: You should add your own answer and accept it so it doesn't sit in the Unanswered queue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved changing status of sub-class: db.Entry(company.Address).State = EntityState.Modified;